# What is the kernel used in the IBM Qiskit's source code?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I want to redefine the QSVM code for a different kernel. But what is the kernel actually used in the IBM Qiskit's source code? And where is it defined, exactly. [QSVC in Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.QSVC.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this link https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/circuit/library/data_preparation/zz_feature_map.html#ZZFeatureMap
to get help on the default kernel being used.